# Thinking Sphinx and searching with multiple fields in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, thinking-sphinx

I'm new in sphinx, and i want to search in a model using sphinx, i did it and it worked well but with one field

this is the field of search

```
<%= form_tag welcome_result_path, target: '_blank' , method: :get do%>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search',name: nil %>
<%end%>
```

this is my action

```
def result
@firms = ThinkingSphinx.search(params[:search],classes:[Firm])
end
```

and this is my index

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :firm, with: :active_record do

# fields
indexes corporate_name, :sortable => true, :as => :rs
indexes id, :as => :newid
indexes external_id, :as => :oldid
indexes gruik_code, :as => :gruik
#indexes country_id, :as => :country  ====> not sure we need this (?)
# indexes usual_corporate_name, :as => :rsu
indexes [contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name], :as => :nom_contact
indexes contacts.role, :as => :role_contact
indexes contacts.contact_methods.value, :as => :second
indexes contacts.contact_methods.method_type, :as => :contact_method
indexes categories(:id), :as => :categorie_id
indexes categories.label, :as => :categorie
indexes [addresses.city.region.name, addresses.free_region], :as => :wilaya
indexes [addresses.street_1, addresses.street_2, addresses.street_3], :as => :adresse
indexes [addresses.city.region.name, addresses.city.name, addresses.street_1, addresses.street_2, addresses.street_3], :as => :ou
indexes [addresses.city.name, addresses.free_city], :as => :ville
indexes tags.name, :as => :tag
indexes categories.tags.name, :as => :categorie_tag
indexes properties.value, :as => :prop
indexes keywords, :as => :keywords
indexes vip_keywords, :as => :vip_keywords
indexes description, :as => :description
end
```

I want to add one more field for the location

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search on a specific field in your Sphinx index, you can use the `:conditions` option in your search call:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(
  params[:search],
  classes:    [Firm],
  conditions: {:location => params[:location]}
)
```

Also, unrelated to your question, but just something from the code you've shared: if you're searching on just one model, you can use the `search` method on that model, instead of passing through the `:classes` option:

```
Firm.search(
  params[:search],
  conditions: {:location => params[:location]}
)
```